# Composer manually dumpautoload

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

The error comes out when I am trying to update or dumpautoload:

> Class "Package\PackageName\Providers\PackageNameProvider" not found

I tried to dumpautoload but it can not be happened because of my composer does not work correctly, so I had copied my project from dev to production manually but still have a problem with some files fetched using old autoload process.
How can I manually dumpautoload those files?

Comment: do all packages install correctly after running `composer update` ? if not try reinstalling with the `-vvv` for a fully detailled log

Comment: This error is not from composer but PHP. Actually your PHP project is broken. Likely a misconfiguration that leads to a race condition at runtime. Restore the last known good configuration and then compare the changes. Apply them in little baby steps to find the culprit. Also restore production, don't deploy versions with known defects.

Comment: composer does not run correctly that is one of the reason i want to dumpautoload manually if i can 
@moghwan

Comment: i guess so @hakre

Answer (score 0):

delete the composer.lock file and run:

```
composer update
```

Comment: this is not a relevant answer because i need to manually dumpautoload and this will not work for me because composer not working properly